# How to only use one buffer for custom readable stream?

Tags: node.js

I've written the following code to buffer some text protocol I'm sending to a service:

```js
  let i = 0;
  let offset = 0;
  const stream = new Readable({
    read() {
      const buf = Buffer.alloc(65536);
      for(; i < points.length; i++) {
        const str = points[i].toLineProtocol();
        if(str.length+offset+1 >= 65536) {
          this.push(buf.slice(0, offset));
          offset = 0;
          return;
        }
        buf.write(str, offset, str.length, 'utf8');
        offset += str.length;
        buf.write('\n', offset, 1, 'utf8');
        offset++;
      }
      this.push(buf.slice(0, offset));
      this.push(null);
    }
  });
```

However when I pull out `buf` from `read()` I am getting fragmented requests. I'm wondering if there is some way to only use one buffer?

**Edit:**

It appears to work properly if I call `this.push(buf.slice(0, offset).toString())`. Does anyone know why it doesn't work with a sliced buffer? The docs say push takes a `Buffer`.

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding

The updated code looks like this:

```js
  let i = 0;
  let offset = 0;
  const buf = Buffer.alloc(65536);
  const stream = new Readable({
    read() {
      for(; i < points.length; i++) {
        const str = points[i].toLineProtocol();
        if(str.length+offset+1 >= 65536) {
          this.push(buf.slice(0, offset).toString());
          offset = 0;
          return;
        }
        buf.write(str, offset, str.length, 'utf8');
        offset += str.length;
        buf.write('\n', offset, 1, 'utf8');
        offset++;
      }
      this.push(buf.slice(0, offset).toString());
      this.push(null);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Isn't that `i--;` wrong? The `i++` shouldn't execute because of the `return;`.

Comment: I think you're right. I'll fix that.

Comment: Your code seems fine? Unless you're not talking about `stream` having trouble, but instead directly accessing `buf` instead.

Comment: When I pull `buf` out of the `read()` function it fragments my requests. As if there's concurrent reads on the buffer. I'm not really understanding why.

Comment: Oh you mean if you define `const buf` outside `read()`? That's because between two `read()` calls, you don't reset your `offset`. You'd push a buffer with 10 bytes, then next `read()` you' add 5 bytes resulting in pushing 15 bytes, even though the first 10 bytes were already pushed once.

Comment: Am I not doing that here `offset = 0;`?

Comment: Not after the loop, no?

Comment: That should only get called once at the end and read won't be called again. Or would you mind showing me a code answer and I'll accept it as the answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what the correct code is. I tried a simple reproduction of your issue but couldn't get it it to actually output something incorrect.

Comment: Yeah I found out that the code works fine if I call `toString()` on the buffer. I edited my main post.